# Como ler o manual de ajuda do Git?

Tags: git, documentação

Estou tentando aprender mais sobre o Git e estou esbarrando em uma questão básica, não sei como ler o manual. Já entendi algumas coisas, mas ainda não sei ao certo para que são utilizados os símbolos: `[]`, `<>` e `()`. Segue exemplo abaixo:

```
git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]
    [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
    [-p|--paginate|-P|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
    [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
    [--super-prefix=<path>]
    <command> [<args>]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tudo o que está entre colchetes são opcionais (lembrando que os colchetes em si não fazem parte da sintaxe, ele só existe para indicar isso na documentação), você usa apenas se fizer sentido para o que quer. Nesse exemplo só um texto é obrigatório, o comando. Não quer dizer que todas combinações são possíveis ou fazem sentido.

Tudo que está entre angulares (menor e maior) são expressões que devem ser escritas, então o que está escrito ali dentro descreve que tipo de expressão espera-se ali, obviamente que não é para escrever aquele texto que está lá só na documentação, mas sim um texto que faça sentido ali. O mais comum é um caminho para um local.

Não vi nada com parênteses. Isto pode variar, pode ser uma agrupamento.

Tem um `|` que significa que você tem que escolher entre essas opções na lista entre esse "operador" de seleção exclusiva, você não pode usar tudo, um é mutualmente exclusivo dos outros da lista.

Isso é mais ou menos padrão para documentações, não é só no Git.

Não tem aí mas há uso de reticências quando cabe uma lista de coisas. Existem notações em algumas documentações para expressar formas de uso de maneira mais sofisticada que a vista aqui, mas a base é essa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Valeu Maniero. ;)

Comment: Este padrão tem algum nome?

Comment: @Francisco que eu saiba não, nunca vi nada muito formal sobre isto.

Comment: Vi esse padrão pela primeira vez nas _man pages_ (manuais, comando [man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page)) do UNIX, por tabela no GNU/Linux é assim também.

Answer (score 3):

Na verdade, André, o **git** como ferramenta é bem mais complexa do que esta prévia do que pode ser feito demonstra. Para usar a ferramenta você precisará inicialmente entender alguns conceitos básicos como: repositório, *branch* e *commit*. Cada comando do **git** tem sintaxe e funcionalidades específicas (quase que um mundo a parte).

Sendo assim, procure tutoriais sobre como usar a ferramenta pois é justamente algo no qual se precisa saber exatamente o que se está fazendo para, claro, foco nos três conceitos básicos pois tudo gira ao redor deles.